# Painting plane with 2 colors (2 points separated by 10 cm different colors )

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Can you paint a plane using 2 colours, so that any 2 points which are separated by 10 cm will have different colours?

Comment: At least 4 colors are needed, and it is not known whether less than 7 will suffice. See the [Hadwiger-Nelson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem).

Answer (score 4):

No you can't, because there are three points that are vertexes of an equilateral triangle with a side of $10\,\rm cm$ and you can't have all 3 vertex colored differently.